# Applying groupby twice on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am storing a huge .csv file in a pandas data frame. The structure of the table is something like this

```
Category       Time      Col1
1              00:00      3
1              01:00      6
1              01:00      10
2              02:00      8
2              02:00      12
2              03:00      6
3              04:00      13
3              05:00      8
```

I want to find the following for every category

[summation(sum of col1 for each time of each category) * (count of col1 for each time in each category)]/(total number of rows) for each
category.

So basically I'm trying to apply group by once on category and then in every category, I want to apply group by again on Time and
compute as above.

So for the above example, my output should look like

```
Category       Col1
1         [3 + (2 * (6 + 10))] / 8
2         [(2 * (8 + 12)) + 6] / 8
3         [13 + 8] / 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `transform` with `sum` create the `count` , then we using `Seriesgroupby` get the result

```
s1=df.groupby(['ategory','Time']).Col1.transform('count')
(s1*df.Col1).groupby(df['ategory']).sum()/df.groupby('ategory').Col1.sum()
Out[631]: 
ategory
1    1.842105
2    1.769231
3    1.000000
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```